# CSS Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression (in Javascript) to get margin, padding and border values, reading them from document.styleSheets

I wrote that:

```
/:\s*?(\d+)(px)?/gi
```

but is not good. The main problem is the the rule should be like:

```
margin: 3px;
margin: 3px 2px;
margin: 3px 2px 1px;
margin: 3px 2px 1px 0;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-left: 3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
```

the same for the padding.
For the border is similar:

```
border: 1px solid #000;
border-width: 1px 1px 2px 0;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
```

I can split the rule and search for each type, something like

```
if(rule.indexOf('margin') > -1) {
    ...
} else if (rule.indexOf('margin-top') > -1) {
    ...
}
```

and use different regex .. but I would like to have the more general regex to avoid a long list of "if".

Can anybody help me?

Many thanks,
da

Comment: Have you considered using a CSS parser?

Comment: Don't forget to take into account that some developers don't always use pixel positioning. You should check for; - em - % - px

Comment: Of course, there is also this variable :(

Comment: What do you mean with CSS parser?

Comment: I mean [a library that can parse CSS without the hackery of using regexes](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+css+parsing+library&oq=javascript+css+parsing+library&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j59l2j60j62.3782&sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&gs_rn=0&gs_ri=serp&tok=AATJ6Ou-QAaXWJr-iroXMA&pq=javascript%20css%20parsing%20library&cp=21&gs_id=7&xhr=t&q=javascript+css+parser&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=javascript+css+parser&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1354675689,d.b2I&fp=8bcffc4a59194800&bpcl=39650382&biw=1301&bih=682).

Answer (score 0):

As the stylesheets can be formatted in several different ways, you should have a look at other alternatives, like the [JSizes jQuery extension plugin](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) that will be very helpful to get those values.

Comment: My problem is exactly that I want to avoid the use of jQuery, because jQuery works on DOM elements and I want to get the total size of an element (what in jQuery is easily done with offsetWidth), before creating the DOM, my porpouse is to improve the performance (even if I'm not so sure that my solution is good)